# Why is Turkmenistan considered one of the most repressive regimes in the world?

Tags: human-rights

There was [an article in The Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2351922/Jennifer-Lopez-forced-apologize-concert-Turkmenistan-singing-happy-birthday-countrys-president-accused-arresting-torturing-political-dissidents.html#ixzz2Xo4XZpwA) that claimed this. The group also reports that:

> Berdimuhamedow leads one of 'the most repressive regimes in the
>   world,' according to Human Rights Watch
>
> 'President Berdymukhamedov, his relatives, and associates enjoy
>   unlimited power and total control over all aspects of public life.'

This seems to be a vague and general claim and the type likely to be exaggerated.  So what actions has President Berdymukhamedov done that has earned him and his regime this label?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Turkmenistan & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_rights_in_Turkmenistan. Also, see http://www.amnesty.org/en/region/turkmenistan/report-2007 if you trust AI.

Comment: Ukbekistan and Tadjikstan are also pretty great in the domain of extreme totalitarism and constant violation of any human rights. Khazakhstan is also a dictatorship, but is more Russia aligned which makes it a bit more civilized. Kirghizstan seems the only countries in the region which didn't go *too* bad.

Comment: These central Asian -stans (except for Kyrgyzstan after the Tulip Revolution) usually adore a strongman, big-tent, male leader that represents the majority ethnicity and have policies that have statist, nationalist, populist and somewhat secular elements. And usually these policies can easily violate human rights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Daily Mail article doesn't specify the exact source of the quotes it's using, but I'm pretty sure their source is the [Human Rights Watch](http://www.hrw.org/) [World Report 2013 on Turkmenistan](http://www.hrw.org/world-report/2013/country-chapters/turkmenistan):

> Following February 2012 presidential elections, President Gurbanguly Berdymukhamedov retained unchallenged power, and Turkmenistan remains one of the world’s most repressive countries.
>
> The country is virtually closed to independent scrutiny, media and religious freedoms are subject to draconian restrictions, and human rights defenders and other activists face the constant threat of government reprisal. The government continues to use imprisonment as a tool for political retaliation.
>
> Turkmenistan continued to expand relations with foreign governments and international organizations in 2012, but without meaningful outcomes for human rights.

The report is fairly long and fully available online, I don't think it would make much sense to copy it here. Other than this report, the HRW maintains a page about [Human Rights in Turkmenistan](http://www.hrw.org/europecentral-asia/turkmenistan) with various other reports and news articles about human rights violations.

Moving on, the [Office of the United Nations High Commissioner for Human Rights](http://www.ohchr.org/EN/Pages/WelcomePage.aspx) (OHCHR) has published various reports on Turkmenistan since 2006 (when Mr. Berdimuhamedow came to power), all with long lists of "areas of concern and recommendations":

- [Concluding observations of the Committee on the Elimination of Discrimination against Women](http://www2.ohchr.org/english/bodies/cedaw/docs/co/CEDAW.C.TKM.CO.3-4.pdf) (2012, PDF)
- [Concluding observations of the Committee on the Elimination of Racial Discrimination](http://www2.ohchr.org/english/bodies/cerd/docs/CERD.C.TKM.CO.6-7.pdf) (2012, PDF)
- [Concluding observations of the Committee against Torture](http://www2.ohchr.org/english/bodies/cat/docs/co/CAT.C.TKM.CO.1.pdf)  (2011, PDF)
- [Concluding observations of the Committee on the Rights of the Child](http://www.unhchr.ch/tbs/doc.nsf/898586b1dc7b4043c1256a450044f331/dfe43af483155c99c125719a00653527/$FILE/G0642491.pdf) (2006, PDF)

Again, those reports are fairly long and can't be easily summarized here, but even a cursory reading indicates that the UN, although a lot more diplomatic in its verbiage, doesn't disagree with the HRW about the status of human rights in Turkmenistan.

### Further reading

- HRW: [Universal Periodic Review: Joint HRW Submission on Turkmenistan with Freedom Now and the Turkmen Initiative for Human Rights](http://www.hrw.org/news/2013/04/19/universal-periodic-review-joint-hrw-submission-turkmenistan-freedom-now-and-turkmen-), submitted in October 2012 (updated in April 2013).
- HRW: [Open Letter to President Berdymukhamedov regarding Ongoing Expropriations and Demolitions](http://www.hrw.org/sites/default/files/TURKM%20-%20Ltr.%20to%20President%20Berdymukhamedov%2025Oct2011.pdf) (PDF), October 2011.
- The Turkmen Initiative for Human Rights mentioned in HRW's periodic review maintains a website, [Chronicles of Turkmenistan](http://www.chrono-tm.org/en/), that tries to ["act as an independent non-governmental information agency"](http://www.chrono-tm.org/en/about-the-web-site/).
- [Norwegian Helsinki Committee](http://nhc.no/en/) (NGO): ["Women: Turkmenistan’s second-class citizens - Equal only to injustice and vulnerable to arbitrariness"](http://www.nhc.no/filestore/Publikasjoner/Rapporter/2012/CEDAW53-Turkmenistan-NHC.pdf) (PDF)
- Amnesty International: [2013 report on Turkmenistan](http://www.amnesty.org/en/region/turkmenistan/report-2013)
- Wikipedia: [Politics of Turkmenistan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Turkmenistan)
- Wikipedia: [Human rights in Turkmenistan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_rights_in_Turkmenistan)

Comment: On the other hand, Turkmen absolutely adore their president. Why else would [97,14% of them vote for him](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkmenistani_presidential_election,_2012)‽